# Update table with values from another table

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

I have these tables:

```
customer:
    customer_id vat_number
    =========== ==========
              1 ES-0000001
              2 ES-0000002
              3 ES-0000003


invoice:
    invoice_id customer_id vat_number
    ========== =========== ==========
           100           1 NULL
           101           3 NULL
           102           3 NULL
           103           2 NULL
           104           3 NULL
           105           1 NULL
```

I want to fill the NULL values at `invoice.vat_number` with the current values from `customer.vat_number`. Is it possible to do it with a single SQL statement?

What I have so far triggers a syntax error:

```
UPDATE invoice
SET vat_number=cu.vat_number /* Syntax error around here */
FROM invoice iv
INNER JOIN customer cu ON iv.customer_id=cu.customer_id
WHERE invoice.invoice_id=iv.invoice_id;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using MySQL, ANSI-92 JOIN syntax:

```
UPDATE INVOICE
  JOIN CUSTOMER ON CUSTOMER.customer_id = INVOICE.customer_id
   SET vat_number = CUSTOMER.vat_number  
 WHERE INVOICE.vat_number IS NULL
```

Using MySQL, ANSI-89 JOIN syntax:

```
UPDATE INVOICE, CUSTOMER 
   SET INVOICE.vat_number = CUSTOMER.vat_number  
 WHERE CUSTOMER.customer_id = INVOICE.customer_id
   AND INVOICE.vat_number IS NULL
```

For [more info, see the MySQL UPDATE documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html).  This is MySQL specific UPDATE statement syntax, not likely to be supported on other databases.

Comment: That's it: UPDATE + JOIN + SET. It's hard to spot from the manual although, now I know how it's done, it's kind of obvious... Thank you very much.

Comment: "ANSI-92 JOIN syntax" is misleading. The syntax posted is not compliant with ANSI-92: doesn't allow a JOIN at all, requires use of scalar subqueries e.g. `UPDATE INVOICE SET vat_number = (SELECT customer_id FROM CUSTOMER WHERE CUSTOMER.customer_id = INVOICE.customer_id) WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM CUSTOMER WHERE CUSTOMER.customer_id = INVOICE.customer_id);`

Comment: ...noting that you later point out that it is proprietary syntax.

Answer (score 4):

```
UPDATE invoice i, customer cu SET i.vat_number=cu.vat_number 
WHERE i.customer_id = cu.customer_id;
```

Here you go

---

SET vat_number=cu.vat_number /* Syntax error around here */
The error is because the var_number column name is ambiguous - MySQL does not know if this is i.vat_number or cu,vat_number.

Comment: Thanks @RC I do not think that he really need a subquery for such a simple task.

Comment: This works fine but I find implicit joins hard to understand. Can this be rewritten as an INNER JOIN?

Comment: Then read what @OMG Ponies have written, but this is the smpliest and I would say best approach.

Comment: My syntax error is because the SET clause should be *after* the join specification. I've just realized that had started coding from a SQL-Server snippet that I had mistakenly taken as MySQL :_(

Comment: This answer is brilliant, I wish I could give it 10 up-votes.

Answer (score 3):

Something like :

```
UPDATE invoice in
SET vat_number=(SELECT cu.vat_number FROM customer cu 
WHERE in.customer_id=cu.customer_id)
-- not tested
```

Comment: This syntax works fine (except that `in` is a reserved keyword). Thank you!

Comment: This assumes that all `INVOICE.vat_number` values are NULL -- those that aren't, will still be overwritten with the `CUSTOMER.vat_number` value.

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE iv
SET iv.vat_number=cu.vat_number
FROM invoice iv
INNER JOIN customer cu ON iv.customer_id=cu.customer_id
```